# U.S. bank refinancing auto loans for for internationally held car

Tags: financial, loan

I'm a U.S. citizen living and working in New Zealand. The auto loan rates in NZ are much worse than the rates I can get in the U.S. (~10% APR vs. ~3% APR in the U.S.). About a year ago I bought a car and while my U.S. bank provides loans for purchasing cars overseas, there were issues with the foreign exchange, and I ended up using a private loan through my U.S. bank to finance the purchase instead. While the rate is still as good or better than auto rates in NZ, I would still like to see if I can refinance and improve my rate. My bank won't refinance an auto loan for a car that's overseas.

Are there banks in the U.S. that offer competitive loan rates on autos held overseas?

Comment: While I can't answer the question, you are aware that if your loan is in USD you are bearing an exchange rate risk in case the USD depreciates wrt NZD.